# Angular route with html5Mode giving 'Not found' page after reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, html5-history

I made some Angular routes as shown in the code bellow.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'home.html',
         controller: 'AppCtrl'
    });
    .when('/portfolio', {
        templateUrl: 'portfolio.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
         $delegate.history = historyCompatCheck();
         return $delegate;
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This works fine, after i set the base href to be "/" it accepted an anchor with the href of "/portfolio", but when i go to "http://url.com/portfiolo" or try to reload the page when i'm on the portfolio route it will give me an server error. Can i do something about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it myself.. you always need to make a .htaccess file in the root of your project. Containing the following:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: I have a strange problem: It works for "simple" urls, like `/something` but it won't work for complex urls, like `/something/else` - Any idea why? (I used your same .htaccess)

Comment: Hi @Alberto, you should try to read and use this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router let me know if it solves your problem :)!

Comment: @Alberto To be more helpful, i think you need to add a <base href="/"> to your <head> in your index.html or index.php ;-)

Comment: How do you link the .htaccess file? Does it automatically load it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#BEGIN
```

Options +FollowSymLinks

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
     RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^(.*) your root folder/index.php [NC,L]

 </ifModule>
   #END
```

its working 100% `<base href="/"></base>`
also add  to your index.html code in `<head>`section