# AngularJS, HTML5 mode routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, github-pages

I am trying to rid my site of Hashbangs but I can't seem to get it quite right.   For example, if I land on my [home page](http://eat-sleep-code.com) and then click on the "CSS" menu and select the "Origami Element" menu option, I briefly see the page load before I am directed to a GitHub 404 page.

If I put the url (http://eat-sleep-code.com/css/origami) in directly, I get sent directly to the GitHub 404.

What am I missing, or is this not possible on a GitHub Pages-hosted AngularJS site?

Below is a partial chunck of my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('eatsleepcode', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']); 

/* Routing */
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {    
        $routeProvider.      
            when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/blog.html', controller: 'BlogController'}).
            when('/blog', {templateUrl: 'views/blog.html', controller: 'BlogController'}).
            when('/blog/:postID', {templateUrl: 'views/blog.html', controller: 'BlogController'}).
            when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'views/contact.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/privacy', {templateUrl: 'views/privacy.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/resources', {templateUrl: 'views/resources.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/terms', {templateUrl: 'views/terms.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/css/origami', {templateUrl: 'views/css/origami.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);  


/* Controllers */
app.controller('DefaultController', function($scope) {});
```

Comment: The server isn't going to read your javascript if you are just requesting http://.../css/origami. The server has no idea how to route that with your js definition. That is the purpose of `#`(http://.../#/css/origami); it breaks the url so it loads the initial page with the javascript, then loads the proper route.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211576/enabling-html-5-mode-in-angularjs-1-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zeroflagL  suggestion got me over my first hurdle.   I had some code that was specifically firing on hashbang URLs.   I had failed to update that IF condition.

Now, clicking on all the links worked fine but entering a URL directly resulted in a 404 error.   Had I been running this site on IIS or Apache I could have rectified the solution by implementing a URL rewrite **(and this would be the ideal way to deal with this)**.

But alas, I am running this on GitHub pages.   They currently (as of 11/25/2014) do not support setting up your own URL rewrite configuration.

They do however, let you setup a custom 404 page.   I setup a simple 404.html page in the root of my GitHub pages site.   This 404 page, inserts the hash AngularJS needs behind the scenes into the URL and then calls a redirect to it.   As we are using a window.location.replace, the 404.html page doesn't show up in the browser history.

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="eatsleepcode">
<head>
    <title><eat-sleep-code /></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/#' + window.location.pathname;
        window.location.replace(url);
    </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

In the event the page doesn't really exist... ie: http://eat-sleep-code.com/somecrazyurl   Angular routing takes over and loads my 404 view.   Perhaps not the most elegant solution but it appears to have worked in a situation where URL rewriting is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `render.min.js` script. When you click on a link then the URL of the current window is changed:

```
window.top.location.href=e
```

Without that it works fine.