# Otherwise Angular js issue

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm currently working on NgRoute configuration. The otherwise is not working when i try a fake route like localhost:8000/dadza.

here the code i tried.

```
$routeProvider

// route for the single page
.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/singlepage.html',
            controller : 'singleController',
            access : { requiredLogin: false}
})
// route for the about page
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});/*
Not working if i try /dzadzada but working if try /#dadzadza*/
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Comment: what do you mean by " route like localhost:8000/dadza."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular route with html5Mode giving 'Not found' page after reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452832/angular-route-with-html5mode-giving-not-found-page-after-reload)

Comment: What's d console error u got

Comment: @Sajeetharan I mean for example this is my url for the home of my website : https://www.example.com/, on my config if i try  https://www.example.com/anything , i got a 404 error, if i try https://www.example.com/#anything the redirection work, what i want to have is that comportement no matter what is after the '/'. I thought  was removing the #/ of /#/, but apparently not.

I got no error Reena.

Austin Mullins, it didn't work for me still got the error.